# tfs build user need to be admin on destination server for web deploy

Tags: package, tfsbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

To deploy via web deploy to IIS7 from Tfs Build - does the user tfs build is running under need to be administrator on the destination server?

I am working with MVC 4 .net app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requiring administrator access is the default, but MSDeploy supports non-administrator deployments as long as you're only deploying files, ACLs and database changes. If you need you deploy IIS settings, you'll still need administrator access.

There are [instructions on configuring non-admin deployments](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy) on iis.net